# Extract data inside parenthesis except being enclosed by semicolon

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Want to extract data inside parenthesis.  But if those parenthesis are inside between single quotes. Then it should be neglected. Using regular expression.

Input:

```
XCA(AA+BB)AA(AD'A(CC)B')
```

Expected Output:

```
AA+BB
AD'A(CC)B'
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by " if those parenthesis are inside any semicolon" perhaps between 2 semi-colons, after a semi-colon, contain a semi-colon???

Comment: You mean single quotes?

Comment: @ValerijDobler you are correct  I mean single quotes here.

Comment: @Kendle here if the parenthesis  are enclosed  by 2 single quotes  then those parenthesis will not be considered as token.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String in="XCA(AA+BB)AA(CC)AD'(CC)'XCA(AA+BB)";
        String result="";
        boolean x=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++){
        char ch = in.charAt(i);
        String part = String.valueOf(ch);
        int number = 0;
        if (ch == '\'' ) {
            part = "";
            number++;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < in.length(); j++) {
                char d = in.charAt(j);
                if (d == '\'') {
                    number++;
                }
                if (d == '\'') {
                    number--;
                    i = j;
                    if (number == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                part += d;
            }

        }
        if (ch == '(' ) {
            part = "";
            number++;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < in.length(); j++) {
                char d = in.charAt(j);
                if (d == '(') {
                    number++;
                }
                if (d == ')') {
                    number--;
                    i = j;
                    if (number == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                part += d;
            }

            System.out.println(part);
        }

        result += part;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
\(
    (
        (
            [^\(\)]+|
            '\(|
            \)'
        )+
    )
\)
```

It consists of three main parts.

1. `[^\(\)]+` Anything that is not an parenthesis
2. `' \(` an escaped open parenthesis `'(`
3. `\)'` an escaped closing parenthesis `)'`

All enclosed in a matching parenthesis literals then an outer group (group 1) without repetition and an inner group with repetition.

The matches in group 1 are

```
AA+BB
AD'(CC)'
```